# How to load an svg from an npm package in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, webpacker

In our company, we have a shared npm package that contains images (SVG's mostly) that we share between applications to be able to update them easier when needed and keep them consistent.

I'm trying to use such an image in our rails app (more specifically in an ERB template), it sounds so simple to me but I can't get it to work. I researched this a lot online and could only find articles about images in SCSS/JS... but not how to load it as a normal image.

Can somebody point me to docs or give a simple example of how to do this? We use both sprockets and webpacker and still use Rails 5.1 (I know we need to update...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npm packages are installed to `<rails root>/node_modules`, so nothing prevents you from doing:

```rb
# config/initializers/assets.rb:

Rails.application.configure do
  # ...
  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
  # ...
end
```

(or just path to your single package)

and then working with these like with regular sprockets `your_package/some_file.svg` (adding to manifest/precompiled files may also be required), file paths will depend on your package structure.

Comment: OMG... I feel so stupid now... the solution is so simple... THANK YOU!